SQLite JOIN giving an argument exception in MAUI application
I have a helper class that I want to extend to include JOIN conditions for a select. The method I'm using looks like this
public async Task<List<TV>> JoinOn<T, TU, TV>(string prop, string asName, Tuple<string, string> comp, string? table1, string? table2) where TV : class, new()
{
    var tbl1 = GetName(typeof(T).ToString());
    var tbl2 = GetName(typeof(TU).ToString());

    try
    {
        var sql = table1 is null ? $"SELECT e.*, d.{prop} as {asName} FROM {tbl1} e JOIN {tbl2} d ON e.{comp.Item1}=d.{comp.Item2}" :
                    $"SELECT e.*, d.{prop} as {asName} FROM {table1} e JOIN {table2} d ON e.{comp.Item1}=d.{comp.Item2}";

       var list = await connection.QueryAsync<TV>(sql);
            return list ?? new List<TV>();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       #if DEBUG
       Debug.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}--{ex.InnerException?.Message}");
       #endif
       return new List<TV>();
    }
}

The caller looks like this
var items = await repository.JoinOn<Employee, Department, object>
     ("Name" , "DepartmentName", new  Tuple<string, string>("DepartmentId", "Id"), "employees", "departments");

I've set the breakpoint in the helper and the SQL command looks fine
SELECT e.*, d.Name as DepartmentName 
FROM employees e 
JOIN departments d ON e.DepartmentId = d.Id

When the app builds, I get an error

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type')

I have tried passing asName as the query parameter (changing the {asName} to ? in the SQL command) and get the same error
I have based my code on https://github.com/icebeam7/DemoFK as it works fine and I can test against a known example. The models have been copied directly.
I know this is a problem in my code, but I'm not sure where.
For comparison, my version can be found at https://github.com/nodoid/MAUIForeignKey

It's complaining about a type.  Is QueryAsync<object> allowed?

With > 1k rep you should know to include the stacktrace in the question and mark the line to which it points.

This has nothing to do with MAUI.

@Julian - it's a MAUI app. Yes, possibly tagging as C# would be slightly more correct....

@TimRoberts - the issue seems to be more how I've set up the model. The original  has         public const string CreateEmployeeTableStatement = $"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {EmployeeTable} (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name VARCHAR(255), DepartmentId INT, FOREIGN KEY(DepartmentId) REFERENCES departments(Id));";
wheres mine is using the SQLite extensions Nuget package and I've  probably  converted it incorectly

Doesn't SQLite-net allow LINQ? The repo tests have some LINQ joins. Have you tried using LINQ JOINs instead of raw SQL?

Is there any reason you are trying to (rather badly) roll your own ORM rather than using an existing one such as EF Core?

As per Tim Roberts' excellent comment, instead of object try making a class to catch the combined properties of interest. Something like:
public class EmployeeWithDepartment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentName { get; set; }
}

Then, change the call to:
var items = await repository.JoinOn<Employee, Department, EmployeeWithDepartment>
     ("Name" , "DepartmentName", new  Tuple<string, string>("DepartmentId", "Id"), "employees", "departments");


Unit test
Since there's no actual MAUI code involved, it was pretty easy to put into MSTest to both reproduce the original ArgumentNullException and validate the fix.
// <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="*" />
static SQLiteAsyncConnection connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(":memory:");

[TestMethod]
public async Task Test_TossSO()
{
    await connection.CreateTableAsync<Employee>();
    await connection.CreateTableAsync<Department>();

    var department1 = new Department { Name = "HR" };
    var department2 = new Department { Name = "IT" };
    await connection.InsertAllAsync(new[]
    {
        department1, department2,
    });

    await connection.InsertAllAsync(new []
    {
        new Employee { Name = "Guy, IV", DepartmentId = department1.Id },
        new Employee { Name = "Person, Other", DepartmentId = department2.Id },
    });

    IEnumerable<object> items;
    var repository = new Repository(connection);
    try
    {
        await 
            repository
            .JoinOn<Employee, Department, object>(
            prop: "Name", 
            asName: "DepartmentName",
            comp: new Tuple<string, string>("DepartmentId", "Id"),
            "employees", "departments");
        Assert.Fail("Because we're expecting it to fail and it didn't do that!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(
            expected: typeof(ArgumentNullException),
            actual: ex.GetType(),
            message: "Expecting to reproduce OP's bug.");
    }
            
    items = await
        repository
        .JoinOn<Employee, Department, EmployeeWithDepartment>(
            prop: nameof(EmployeeWithDepartment.Name),
            asName: nameof(EmployeeWithDepartment.DepartmentName),
            comp: new Tuple<string, string>(nameof(Employee.DepartmentId), nameof(EmployeeWithDepartment.Id)),
            "employees", "departments");

    Assert.AreEqual(
        expected: 2, 
        actual: items.Count(),
        message: "This test case should return 2 items");

    Console.WriteLine("Name".PadRight(25) + " | Department");
    Console.WriteLine("====".PadRight(25) + " | ==========");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join( 
        Environment.NewLine,
        items
        .OfType<EmployeeWithDepartment>()
        .Select(_ => $"{_.Name.PadRight(25)} | {_.DepartmentName}")));
}
[Table("employees")]
public class Employee
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}
[Table("departments")]
public class Department
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeeWithDepartment
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public interface IRepository
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection Connection { get; }
}
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public SQLiteAsyncConnection Connection { get; private set; }

    public Repository(SQLiteAsyncConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
    }
    public async Task<List<TV>> JoinOn<T, TU, TV>(string prop, string asName, Tuple<string, string> comp, string? table1, string? table2) where TV : class, new()
    {
        var tbl1 = typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<TableAttribute>()?.Name ?? typeof(T).Name;
        var tbl2 = typeof(TU).GetCustomAttribute<TableAttribute>()?.Name ?? typeof(TU).Name;
        var sql = table1 is null ? $"SELECT e.*, d.{prop} as {asName} FROM {tbl1} e JOIN {tbl2} d ON e.{comp.Item1}=d.{comp.Item2}" :
                    $"SELECT e.*, d.{prop} as {asName} FROM {table1} e JOIN {table2} d ON e.{comp.Item1}=d.{comp.Item2}";

        var list = await connection.QueryAsync<TV>(sql);
        return list ?? new List<TV>();

        // I had to remove the error handling for the unit test to detect the exception.
    }
}



A repository with a Join method isn't a repository, it's a SQL builder. A repository is supposed to hide the database concepts from the rest of the code. Take a look at SqlKata, a popular query builder, especially the Join example. You could also use LINQ joins with SQLite-net, eg _db.Table<Employee>().Join<Department>(e=>e.DepartmentId,d=>d.Id,(e,d)=>...)...

Agreed. While I wanted to stay on topic and keep the form of the code, the method itself might better lend itself to being an extension e.g. public static async Task<List<TV>> JoinOn<T, TU, TV>(this SQLiteAsyncConnection acnx, string prop, string asName, Tuple<string, string> comp, string? table1, string? table2) where TV : class, new(){...}

The error is just the symptom of the real problem - complicated code that tries to replicate what's already available in unsafe ways. The code is vulnerable to SQL injection due to string interpolation and yet gives the impression of type-safety due to its syntax. An unexpected ' or , in one of the parameters though will result in an invalid or unexpected query. Worse, errors are simply hidden away so it's impossible to find out what's wrong.

Let me be clear(er) that I don't disagree with any of that. But in the narrow scope of the question SQLite JOIN giving an argument exception I thought that Tim Roberts hit the nail on the head and wanted to see if I could prove out that singular premise.
